# Downloaded template that has a Scandir wont scan current folder

Tags: php, scandir

I downloaded a free Template named "Cute File Browser" and it has a directory scanner.  It ATM scans a folder named files, but i want it to scan it's own folder "Current folder" i have tired using (./) and some other stuff.

But that didn't work at all !
Here is pastebin for the php code: http://pastebin.com/iR6ts0x4

Not sure what to do, and i want it to scan it's own folder.

I want to use this template because i do not know how to code something myself and i dont want to pay for a template to be made, this one is simple and looks easy to use. I just need it to work my way :)

Thank you !

Comment: We are not general software tech support. I'd suggest contacting whoever wrote that.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with just a . and it scans "Current folder".

```
$dir = ".";
```

Comment: Just says (No files here.) when i used ($dir = ".";)